# Flutter The plugin open_file_manager requires Android SDK version 34. For more information about build configuration

Tags: android, flutter

One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\User\3D Objects\android_as_app\android\app\build.gradle:
`android { compileSdkVersion 34 ... }`

How Can I Resolve ???

Warning: The plugin open_file_manager requires Android SDK version 34.
For more information about build configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as stated in the error log, you should open the android `app` module's `build.gradle`, find `compileSdkVersion` (or simply `compileSdk`) in the `android` section, and change its value to 34